# Prove the trigonometric identity: $\coth^{-1}(\frac{2}{x}) = \cosh^{-1}(x)$ for $x \neq 0 $

Tags: trigonometry

Show that if $x \neq 0$ than

$$\coth^{-1}(\frac{2}{x}) = \cosh^{-1}(x)$$

I suspect that I should probably use *Euler's formula* and express both sides in terms of: $$\sinh(x) = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}$$ and $$\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}$$

So, I start like:

$$\coth^{-1}(\frac{2}{x}) = \frac{\sinh(\frac{2}{x})}{\cosh(\frac{2}{x})}=$$ 
$$=\frac{e^{\frac{2}{x}} - e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}{e^{\frac{2}{x}} + e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}=$$

and  I don't know whether I should divide or do somethinkg else?

---

Here is an excerpt from the book as it is given <sup>(in Greek)</sup>:

[image]

Comment: @Ziezi: with $\cosh^{-1}$ you mean $1/\cosh$ or $\text{arcosh}$?

Comment: @b00nheT Personally, $\cosh^{-1}(x)$ = $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$, as the book uses $arc$ in case of the latter.

Comment: As Claude had initially written in its comment, the estimate doesn't seem to hold for all $x$, in the case you define $\cosh^{-1}$ as you said. Anyways: are you certain that this identity is correct? Because $x=2$ gives a clear counterexample.
Lastly: it is **ar**$\cosh$ and not **arc*$\cosh$. (area-cosine)

Comment: @b00nheT I just uploaded the exercises as it is stated in the book. For the $ar$ or $arc$ I could do with either.

Comment: The interpretation with the reciprocal is very unlikely because it wouldn't add anything to the problem statement (then equivalent to $\coth(2/x)=\cosh(x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the interpretation (inverse or reciprocal), the identity doesn't hold just for the fact that the hyperbolic cotangent is an odd function while the hyperbolic cosine is even.

---

Also note that

$$\coth(\text{arcosh}(x))=\frac{\cosh(\text{arcosh}(x))}{\sinh(\text{arcosh}(x))}=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ne\frac2x.$$

Comment: Perhaps that is the answer: _"The identity doesn't hold."_

Answer (score 1):

$$ \cosh^{-1}(x) \ne sech(x), $$
so the given proposition is incorrect.

Comment: I do not understand this answer: $\mathrm{sech}(x)=\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}!$
Did you miss the OPs definition?

Comment: @gammatester: IMO the OP didn't define anything and just misinterpreted the formula.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Mybe, but see the second comment for the question. I cannot verify his claim that the book uses *ar* for inverse function.